# JQuery cant fathom out how to sort these dates in multiple option selects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, sorting

I'm trying to remove and sort dates in multiple dropdowns using JQuery

basically we have course dates and I dont want to show any courses that have passed. So I decided to:

1. remove any date before today
2. sort in date order the remaining dates left

I tried to do it in one function but failed. I'm able to do it for one date, but can't work out how to loop over multiple dropdowns. (I guess I need to loop over them somehow)

This is the HTML (in this example there are only 2 dates with the ID tag pa_date_11 and pa_date_12 (the numbers change by product adn there may be more than 2))

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
    <h1 class="product_title entry-title">
        Nail Technician Package</h1>
    <p class="price"></p>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <p>Save £25 by booking these 2 popular courses together. This package covers the two most popular methods of nail extensions. You’ll learn UV Gel extensions, UV Gel polish and also Acrylic Nail Extensions in this 2 day course.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="loud-link">
        <a class="smooth-scroll" href="#tab-title-description">Full description →</a>
    </p>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="cart cart_group bundle_form layout_default group_mode_parent bundle_out_of_stock bundle_insufficient_stock initialized">
        <div class="bundled_item_11 bundled_product bundled_product_summary product">

            <div class="details">
                <h4 class="bundled_product_title product_title"><span class="bundled_product_title_inner"><span class="item_title">UV Gel Polish Course | 1/2 Day Course</span><span class="item_qty"></span><span class="item_suffix"></span></span> <span class="bundled_product_title_link"><a class="bundled_product_permalink" href="#" target="_blank" aria-label="View product"></a></span></h4>
                <div class="bundled_product_excerpt product_excerpt">
                    <p>The perfect way to apply a silky smooth and long-lasting UV Gel polish to nails. Gel polish is the ideal salon treatment as it takes only 30 minutes to apply and gives a gloss lacquer finish which lasts up to three weeks.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart bundled_item_cart_content variations_form" data-title="UV Gel Polish Course | 1/2 Day Course" data-product_title="UV Gel Polish Course | 1/2 Day Course" data-visible="yes" data-optional_suffix="" data-optional="no" data-type="variable" data-product_variations="" data-bundled_item_id="11" data-custom_data="{&quot;bundle_id&quot;:4984,&quot;bundled_item_id&quot;:11}" data-product_id="4888" data-bundle_id="4984" current-image="">
                    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="attribute_options attribute_value_configurable" data-attribute_label="Course Location">
                                <td class="label">
                                    <label for="pa_location_11">Course Location <abbr class="required" title="Required option">*</abbr></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="value"><span class="sfblocks-select-wrap"><select id="pa_location_11" class="" name="bundle_attribute_pa_location_11" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_location" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                                            <option value="newark" class="attached enabled">Newark</option>
                                        </select></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="attribute_options attribute_value_configurable" data-attribute_label="Course Date">
                                <td class="label">
                                    <label for="pa_date_11">Course Date <abbr class="required" title="Required option">*</abbr></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="value"><span class="sfblocks-select-wrap"><select id="pa_date_11" class="" name="bundle_attribute_pa_date_11" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_date" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                                            <option value="24-09-2020" class="attached enabled">24/09/2020</option>
                                            <option value="24-12-2020" class="attached enabled">24/12/2020</option>
                                            <option value="12-12-2020" class="attached enabled">12/12/2020</option>
                                        </select></span>
                                    <div class="reset_bundled_variations" style="display: none;"><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear</a></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="single_variation_wrap bundled_item_wrap">
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation bundled_item_cart_details" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button bundled_item_after_cart_details bundled_item_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
                            <input type="hidden" class="variation_id" name="bundle_variation_id_11" value="">
                            <div class="quantity quantity_hidden">
                                <input class="qty bundled_qty" type="hidden" name="bundle_quantity_11" value="1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundled_item_12 bundled_product bundled_product_summary product">
            <div class="details">
                <h4 class="bundled_product_title product_title"><span class="bundled_product_title_inner"><span class="item_title">Nail Extension Acrylic | 1 Day Course</span><span class="item_qty"></span><span class="item_suffix"></span></span> <span class="bundled_product_title_link"><a class="bundled_product_permalink" href="#" target="_blank" aria-label="View product"></a></span></h4>
                <div class="bundled_product_excerpt product_excerpt">
                    <p>This is an exclusive one day course covering all aspects of acrylic extension nail application. You will apply natural-looking tips and learn how to blend them into the natural nail to create a perfect extension.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart bundled_item_cart_content variations_form" data-title="Nail Extension Acrylic | 1 Day Course" data-product_title="Nail Extension Acrylic | 1 Day Course" data-visible="yes" data-optional_suffix="" data-optional="no" data-type="variable" data-product_variations="" data-product_id="4881" data-bundle_id="4984" current-image="">
                    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="attribute_options attribute_value_configurable" data-attribute_label="Course Location">
                                <td class="label">
                                    <label for="pa_location_12">Course Location <abbr class="required" title="Required option">*</abbr></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="value"><span class="sfblocks-select-wrap"><select id="pa_location_12" class="" name="bundle_attribute_pa_location_12" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_location" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                                            <option value="newark" class="attached enabled">Newark</option>
                                        </select></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="attribute_options attribute_value_configurable" data-attribute_label="Course Date">
                                <td class="label">
                                    <label for="pa_date_12">Course Date <abbr class="required" title="Required option">*</abbr></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="value"><span class="sfblocks-select-wrap"><select id="pa_date_12" class="" name="bundle_attribute_pa_date_12" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_date" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                                            <option value="03-10-2020" class="attached enabled">03/10/2020</option>
                                            <option value="13-10-2020" class="attached enabled">13/10/2020</option>
                                            <option value="23-09-2020" class="attached enabled">23/09/2020</option>
                                            <option value="14-12-2020" class="attached enabled">14/12/2020</option>
                                            <option value="02-12-2020" class="attached enabled">02/12/2020</option>
                                            <option value="01-12-2020" class="attached enabled">01/12/2020</option>
                                        </select></span>
                                    <div class="reset_bundled_variations" style="display: none;"><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear</a></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="single_variation_wrap bundled_item_wrap">
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation bundled_item_cart_details" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button bundled_item_after_cart_details bundled_item_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
                            <input type="hidden" class="variation_id" name="bundle_variation_id_12" value="">
                            <div class="quantity quantity_hidden">
                                <input class="qty bundled_qty" type="hidden" name="bundle_quantity_12" value="1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundled_item_13 bundled_product bundled_product_summary product">
            <div class="details">
                <h4 class="bundled_product_title product_title"><span class="bundled_product_title_inner"><span class="item_title">Nail Extension UV Gel | 1 Day Course</span><span class="item_qty"></span><span class="item_suffix"></span></span></h4>
                <div class="bundled_product_excerpt product_excerpt">
                    <p>This is an exclusive one day course covering all aspects of UV Gel extension nail application. You will apply natural looking tips and learn how to blend them into the natural nail to create a perfect extension.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart unavailable_item variations_form" data-title="Nail Extension UV Gel | 1 Day Course" data-product_variations="[]" data-product_title="Nail Extension UV Gel | 1 Day Course" data-visible="yes" data-optional_suffix="" data-optional="no" data-type="variable" data-bundled_item_id="13" data-custom_data="" data-product_id="4879" data-bundle_id="4984" current-image="">
                    <div class="bundled_item_wrap">
                        <div class="bundled_item_cart_content">
                            <div class="bundled_item_cart_details">
                                <p class="bundled_item_unavailable ">Please call to arrange a date</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart bundle_data bundle_data_4984" data-bundle_price_data="" data-bundle_id="4984">
            <div class="bundle_unavailable woocommerce-info">This product is currently unavailable, please call us to arrange a date.</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my JQuery so far

```
// remove any dates older than today function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.removeOldDates = function () {
        $("select[id^='pa_date_'] > option").each(function () {
            //console.log(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
            const now = new Date().getTime();
            const time = this.text.split(/[\s/-]+/); // split the time,  by / or -
            const day = time[0];
            const month = time[1] - 1;
            const year = time[2];
            //console.log(time);
            const row_date = new Date();
            const test = row_date.setFullYear(year, month, day);
            // now we have both times, we can compare them
            if (now > row_date.getTime() || this.text == "") {
                // if the date is less that today or empty remove it from the dropdown
                $("select[id^='pa_date_'] > option[value=" + this.value + "]").remove();
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

// re-order the dates function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.orderDates = function () {
        $(this)
            .find("option:not(:first)")
            .each(function (index, value) {
                const t = this.textContent.split(/[\s/-]+/);
                $(this).data("_ts", new Date(t[2], t[1] - 1, t[0]).getTime());
                console.log(t);

                $(this)
                    .sort(function (a, b) {
                        return $(a).data("_ts") - $(b).data("_ts");
                    })
                    .appendTo("#pa_date_12");
                //$(this).html("select[id^=pa_date_]" + index);
                //$(this).html( $('<option value="Loo">Loo' +  index  + '</option>') );
            });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

// Map the date drop downs
$("select[id^=pa_date_]").each(function (index) {
    console.log(index);
    // $(this) refers to one specific <select> element
    // $(this).append('<option value="foo">Bar ' + index + '</option>');
    $(this).removeOldDates();
    $(this).orderDates();
});
```

I also have it in a Codepen if you wanted to fork and ammend https://codepen.io/xgstq/pen/jOrZwKq

Im getting stuck on the .sort method within the orderDates function as its returning NAN and then appending it to the relevent dropdown.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where are your dates being populated from and in what format? I.e., your Codepen example has the dates hard-coded into the HTML, but I suspect they're actually being populated from elsewhere. Right? It's much easier to work with the data before you populate the Options vs. extracting the data from the `select`, converting it to a preferred format, operating on it, and then pushing it back into the DOM.

Comment: I agree with @Marc 's comment, handle this task on the server but, I think the problem with your code is that you have not set `data("_ts")` on all the elements before you try to sort them as `number - undefined` will return `NAN` or also maybe `data("_ts")` is a string?

Comment: @Marc the dates are generated from WordPress Woocommerce Product Variations, the dates generated do sort themselves but only if the dates are in US format.

I might re-visit it again and have another look at adding dates in US format to the backend and outputting in UK format on the front end.

I think I recall that it didnt really matter because once I converted them on the front end to UK format it messed up the ASC order anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end, I was closing the each (`function()`) too late.

This is my final jQuery:

```
// remove any dates older than today function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.removeOldDates = function () {
        $("select[id^='pa_date_'] > option").each(function () {
            const now = new Date().getTime();
            const time = this.text.split(/[\s/-]+/); // split the time,  by / or -
            const day = time[0];
            const month = time[1] - 1;
            const year = time[2];
            const row_date = new Date();
            const test = row_date.setFullYear(year, month, day);
            // now we have both times, we can compare them
            if (now > row_date.getTime() || this.text == "") {
                // if the date is less that today or empty remove it from the dropdown
                $("select[id^='pa_date_'] > option[value=" + this.value + "]").remove();
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

// re-order the dates function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.orderDates = function () {
        $(this).find("option:not(:first)")
            .each(function (index, value) {
                const t = this.textContent.split(/[\s/-]+/);
                $(this).data( "_ts", new Date(t[2], t[1] - 1, t[0]).getTime() );

                }).sort(function (a, b) {
                        return $(a).data("_ts") - $(b).data("_ts");
                    }).appendTo($(this));

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

// Map the date drop downs
$("select[id^=pa_date_]").each(function (index) {
    $(this).removeOldDates();
    $(this).orderDates();
});
```

I'll definitely revisit the woocommerce and take another look before implementing it

Thanks